# Using Twilio VoiceBase Add-On, VoiceBase API Key Needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am recording a phone call in my app. AFTER the call is done the user can choose to have the recording transcribed by clicking a button. Then we send the transcription request to VoiceBase.

I've tried the [VoiceBase API ruby gem](https://github.com/popuparchive/voicebase-client-ruby) and the documentation from [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/voicebase.html) on Twilio's blog and VoiceBase's [page dedicated to the Twilio integration](https://www.voicebase.com/twilio-integration/).

It's pretty easy to send the curl request to reference the recording hosted by Twilio, but my requests are not accepted because I do not have an API key for VoiceBase. Where do I get the API key?

Comment: http://info.voicebase.com/request-api-key

Comment: So my API key will not be tied to my Twilio account or the Twilio Add-on directly? Then how does VoiceBase handle billing?
Also, the link you shared requires me to apply for the API key. It looks like this is not for people who are using it through Twilio.

Comment: Ask the customer support instead of Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are making the request to VoiceBase conditionally after the call has been made then it is not handled by the Twilio intergration and you will need your own VoiceBase API key and billing account.

If you want all calls transcribed automatically by the VoiceBase Add-on to Twilio, then the billing is handled through Twilio and you don't need to make any other accounts, you just need to enable the [Add-on in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons).

Let me know if that helps at all.